# TransformerFactory.newInstance(...) is vulnerable to XML and XSLT External Entity attacks

Tags: java, xml, xslt, sonarqube

I'm running Java 8 and SonarQube tells me that using TransformerFactory.new Instance() is vulnerable to external XML and XSLT attacks.

I'm trying to insert the ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET attributes into my TransformerFactory to avoid XML and XSLT External Entity attacks.
Searching forums, I see that the solution is to add the following attributes to the TransformerFactory:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

But that doesn't work for me. It tells me that the attributes do not exist.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Is your objective to be secure, or to get rid of the security warnings? It's quite possible to achieve either of these aims without achieving the other. The first questions to ask are (a) do you trust the XSLT code, and (b) do you trust the XML? If you don't trust either, then you need to think much more deeply about security than this. If you trust both, then ignore the warnings.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response. I cannot ignore the warnings because the client has marked them as blocking code. I also don't know why I should prevent my code from possible attacks if I am the one creating the XML and displaying it on a screen. There is no option for the user to insert an XML.

Comment: Searching what forums? Citation please.

Comment: I feared as much. You need to explain to your client that security scanners are pretty stupid. They flag things up for attention, but the flags don't mean that there is a security problem, only that you need to think about it and consider whether there is a problem or not.

Comment: Hi @user207421, https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#transformerfactory or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086062/how-to-secure-javax-xml-transform-transformerfactory-from-xml-external-attacks?rq=3 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution and now it does detect the attributes:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

I don't know if it's the right thing to do but it works and keeps the sonar from complaining.

Comment: The difference from your original code is that you are now loading a specific XSLT processor rather than using the JAXP factory mechanism to find whatever processor is on the classpath. Since the one you were loading before apparently doesn't support these security properties, that's probably a good way forward. But switching to a different XSLT engine is something that might have consequences, so be aware what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Michael. I apreciate it!